# Mass Effect 2 Choices Stats

Tags: mass-effect-2

I remember in pre release interviews some of the devs mentioning we can see stats for the choices that people made in ME2, along the lines of, how many players chose this choice vs that choice, etc.

Is there anywhere I can see those stats? Very curious. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean like the results of "how many times the average player completed a Mass Effect playthrough" and "what percentage of players use female Shepherd vs. male Shepher"?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer right on. They said that we would be able to see things like how many players cheated on their ME1 love interests and the like, maybe that never materialized?

Answer (score 4):

There was an IGN interview with one of the devs where they talked about some of them. [IGN Interview](http://pc.ign.com/articles/111/1118657p1.html). Here is a [blog post](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=406546) where they summarize the same article.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a ME1 character into ME2, these stats are shown on the character creation screen. These stats are not very detailed however but it gives you the jist of what your ME1 character was all about it.

Comment: This is not the question. Sorry about any confusion